# How can a mindmap be integrated (visualized) on an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, mindmapping

On my R shiny webapp, I would like to present some information in the form of a mindmap. I am generating the mindmap using certain free tools available.

(An example mindmap below: the actual one would have many more nodes and connections)

[image: Example mindmap]

Is there a possibility to visualize a mindmap interactively such as expanding/collapsing subtrees upon selection, on the shiny app? Currently I only know visualizing the mindmap as an exported image, however that would not be very user friendly for a larger map.

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at visNetwork